# Natural selection "intent": eg humans are not "designed" to work in zero-G

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If one subscribes to the principles of natural selection, then the phrase "humans are not designed to work in zero-G" is incorrect; natural selection does not *design* anything. What word could be substituted for "design"? Or perhaps some other concise phrasing?

Comment: I think it's clear that *designed* is not meant literally in the given context. Anyway, you could replace it with *adapted*.

Comment: Have you considered *evolved* or *developed*?

Answer (score 1):

Humans have not evolved to work in zero-G.